# Tableau - Keeping Booleans independent (not aggregated into all possible combos.)

Tags: graph, charts, bar-chart, data-visualization, tableau-api

I have several Boolean variables. I am trying get get them displayed as columns, side by side, with a height that is based on the measure on the Y axis. Tableau is combining the Booleans, making each column a possible combination of all the Booleans - {0,0,0,1}, {0,0,1,0}, ...

I am also only interested in the cases where the Boolean is True.

How do I get Tableau to treat the Booleans independently? I tried experimenting with filtering, but if I exclude the 0 values for one Boolean, all of that data is removed - and I need that data for the other columns.

Creating a calculated field - "if [bool-val] = 1 then 1 end" does not stop the aggregating into all possible combinations.

As requested, here is what the chart looks like.  I added the sets of 1's and 0's as examples of the combinations Tableau is making.

A, B, C, and D are Boolean fields.  Z is a measure.

What I want is 4 columns, where A=1, B=1, C=1, and D=1, where each
column has a height Z, independent of the other Boolean values.

[image]

Here's the format of the data.  (The actual values won't match the chart above.)

[image]

Comment: Could you please at some pictures of your current chart, and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: I added a graphic as requested.

Comment: What do you want it to look like instead? Especially explain Z. Does the height of Z indicate the number of records that have a true value for A? B? Etc or something else?

Comment: I want 4 columns, each representing the number of Z that is associated with the particular Boolean variable.  Say that Z is the total number of members of the animal kingdom that are represented in the data set. Say that A represents whether the animal is a mammal, B represents whether the animal primarily lives in the water, C represents whether the animal is a bird, and D represents whether a female raises offspring without the assistance of other members of her species. In the case of a dolphin being added to the data set, A, B, and D would be incremented by 1. (Continued.)

Comment: The heights of A,B,C, and D represents the occurrence of that trait, independent of other traits.  ---  It is easy to get Tableau to do this with a categorical variable.  However, with a categorical variable, a given record can be assigned to only one category.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the pivot functionality in the data preview/prep area. Highlight columns A, B, C, and D. Right-click and choose Pivot. This will turn each column into a separate row. Instead of having A, B, C, D on your Columns shelf, drag the pivoted dimension to your Columns shelf. This should get you Z values for the individual boolean counts.

See Tableau Help at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.html for more details on pivoting your data.

Comment: I read the link.  This data is not in cross tab format, nor can it be converted to that format.  There is no option to pivot when highlighting the columns in Tableau, and right-clicking.  The link you gave says to do it in the data source.  When I select the columns and hit the arrow, I get a menu item like in the link, except the pivot option is not there.  (It should be between 'Create Calculated Field' and Merge Mismatched Fields, but its missing.)  The option is missing because this isn't cross tab data.

Comment: @MikeSmith Can you edit your question and add a sample of your data?

Comment: I added equivalent data at the end. The format matches the Tableau chart above it.

Comment: The data looks like I expected. What version of Desktop are you using?

Comment: Tableau Desktop Pro 10.3.3

Comment: Are the fields you are attempting to pivot calculated fields?

Comment: No. And the data isn't live.  It's an extract.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tableau can't do this.
I created a new table in MySQL that sets the fields doing selects.
Here's the format of the table (2x4):

```
M = A,  P = average of Z where A = 1
M = B,  P = average of Z where B = 1
M = C,  P = average of Z where C = 1
M = D,  P = average of Z where D = 1
```

Placing M on Columns and P on Rows give the graph I want.